# Minify Javascript with namespace

Tags: javascript, minify

Is there any javascript minifier out there (online one) which allows defining a namespace? I mean all these minifiers generates code with short variable names like a,b,c ... which may cause conflicts with other minified javascript.

Comment: Don't write your codes in the global scope. It's like a public restroom, you want minimize your exposure. Wrap you code in a self-executing anonymous function.

Comment: Most minifiers let you specify which names you don't want changed

Comment: @mikeycgto: ould you give me a quick suggestion how to achive that?

Comment: http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/

Comment: as far as i know, closure compiler needs all scripts that are inter-related to be present for them to be properly minified. otherwise, if you just had half your code minified with closure and the other half depended on it was not minified with it, it will not work. you should minify only for production, and that means all scripts.

Comment: The Closure Compiler can be given an option to only minify variables it knows are in a limited scope and leave global variable/function names unmodified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most (good) minifiers leave globally scoped variables alone since those are the namespace we're in by default.  mikeycgto was suggesting that you make sure you keep those down to a minimum:

```
var page = ( function(){
  var scopedVar = "I'm something like private.";

  //do some other stuff

  return {
    usefulThing: function(){
        return scopedVar;
    }
  };
}() );
```

Running that through a minifier should leave you with a "page" var in the global scope.  page.usefulThing is a method (which should also be left alone by the minifier).  "scopedVar" may be turned into "a" or "o" or somesuch, but you'll never care.  Your API will remain as expected though the internals will be mucked about with.